# Forward Traffic on Port through SSH Reverse Tunnel

Tags: ssh

I have an interesting scenario. I've searched every where, and I have bits and pieces of information, however, I don't have the full picture, and it's driving me nuts.

I also want to mention I'm no where near sysadmin status, however, I can get around my infrastructure with enough to get the job done.

I've got 3 end points. I've got a device inside a network (endpoint#1), that's setup a reverse tunnel to one of my servers (endpoint#2). I've got another server that has to send requests (endpoint#3) to the device (endpoint#1) through the connection server (endpoint#2).

I'm currently able to sustain connections between endpoint#1 and endpoint#2, and send requests from endpoint#2 to endpoint#1 without issue, however, I need endpoint#3 to be able to talk to endpoint#1 through endpoint#2.

I've tried searching for port forwarding scenarios and reverse tunnel scenarios, however, whatever it is that I'm doing is not allowing network traffic through.

How can I set up http traffic to GET/POST from endpoint#3 to endpoint#2 and pass through to endpoint#1 through the specified reverse tunnel (on it's specified port)? HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It's using roughly the same syntax that I'm using on SSH to setup the remote server, however, it's adding the binding ip address (interal ip address of the network that it's on) and using GatewayPorts clientspecified in the sshd_config (although, I'm not 100% I needed this - it is an option I set though).

On **endpoint#1**:
- ssh -R [endpoint#2.internal.ip.address]:[port]:[localhost]:[port-to-map-to-on-endpoint#1] user@endpoint#2

On **endpoint#3**:
- curl -X POST -d {data} http://endpoint#2.internal.ip.address/path/to/resource

This will then allow the call on endpoint#3 to be passed through to endpoint#1.